Combobox ItemTemplate not refreshing when IsAsync = true
I have a combobox template with some fields that take a long time to return their values. So I tried setting IsAsync=true for those fields so that the dropdown should open quickly. The desired result is that the values which have IsAsync set should show later when they are ready, however they do not get updated at all, they only show when an item is selected.
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <DockPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Right">                    
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding NumNotAssigned,IsAsync=true}" />

Looks like this (dropdown part):

but should look like this (selected item part):


You should try to improve how data is provided instead of using adync data binding. The waiting time for the user is not eliminated by async data binding. You could preload data in the background or cache data. Whatever  causes the delay, you should try to fix that first.

By the way, how can an even incomplete XAML tag snippet allow others to review your code in order to find your error? Please take your time to post a proper question that contains a minimal reproducible example. Then you can get code reviews, if that makes sense.

@BionicCode I will investigate speeding up the returned values, that is most certainly the best option. However if I cannot do that, then Async option at least loads the screen quickly, so that the user can get on, and eventually will also see these values when they are returned. The Async method works well elsewhere, it is just the dropdown part of the combobox which seems to have a problem with being notified of refreshed data.

I think from an UX perspective, it's weird to open a drop down where only half of the content is loaded. The user doesn't know that content is missing. And even if he learns that, this feels just odd. I don't know your context. But in general, I would improve the data handling (e.g. data virtualization, caching, background initialization,... etc). If improving this does improve the bindig issue but does not fix it, I would continue and implement a busy indicator: the user opens the drop down --> show an empty panel with a busy indicator.

Then wait for the data to be ready and present all data at once when done instead of incomplete data. Because data handling has been optimized in the first step, I would expect the busy indicator to show only for a brief time. This will significantly improve the overall UX.

Unless you have to perform a real-time query to a data service, there is no reason that the ComboBox data can't be preloaded (e.g. from a database). If data is queried in real-time you can still cache the responses. You were not specific about your problem. But I assume that you are not using data virtualization. Instead, you load all data at once. In this case this will also cause the UI to freeze (maybe this is what you are experiencing and not slow computed properties). In this case you would have to enable UI virtualization for the ComboBox.

You probably confuse the slow loading time of the ComboBox with slow data source properties. Please post a minimal reproducible example that shows how you load the data. Just create a new project and reproduce the issue. Only then can we know what's going on and how to fix it.

@BionicCode, On my App after login success, I load all tables in IEnumerable<T> to fill ComboBoxes later from cache, then showing the Mainwindow, that's kind of confirms what you have said. In case of (real-time) I would suggest to load the simple data Column 0,1 first from database to allow opening the ComboBox and create a CustomControl for Column 2 to load the rest of data with that busy indicator and so on.

@MustafaMutasim I believe that presenting the user with an incomplete view provides a bad UX. The user is tempted to interact with the view if something is present. That's fine so far. But if he needs the missing information to make a choice then the waiting will subjectively feel longer. You can load and present data incrementally if they belong to different scopes of action. Otherwise, a particular action should only be made available when the necessary UI context is loaded. The user will not understand why certain logically or visually related data takes longer to load.

@MustafaMutasim These are application internal details. It's said that psychologically waiting feels shorter when you wait for the complete result opposed to waiting and watching while something is gradually building before you can use it. As soon something is visible you want to use it, that's the point.

@MustafaMutasim For example, you would show a data row in a table only if the complete row data is available. A data row is potentially meaningless or dangerous if you show it gradually column by column. The user wants to see the row and once the row is visible, he wants to interact with it. Let the user wait once and then allow him to operate without interruption. And to avoid input errors or operating errors (because the user could potentially miss the fact that the row has missing columns) you would have to grey out the incomplete row object. Which would lead to another odd situation.

@MustafaMutasim In addition, your example requires the developer to know about the data. For example, in a table that lists chemicals that are used to create solutions, it could be ok if the chemical column is showing while the manufacturer column is still missing. But it could be fatal if the chemical column shows up but the warning column that certain chemicals are not allowed to get mixed does not. From this point of view alone it's easier to only show a row when all cell information is available. While this argument is context related the design rules in terms of UX are not.

@BionicCode, You bring a wealth of knowledge and experience to the table, I am continually impressed by your ingenuity and problem-solving skills. Thank you for your dedication to our success

@MustafaMutasim I'm not sure if your comment was meant sarcastic or if they were very kind words. I'm just responding to your comments trying to discuss the suggestions. I only try to make an argument by explaining the ideas. I never meant to annoy you.

@BionicCode, sarcastic ??!! no at all and will never, that was a simple words to thank you for your efforts and devotion, I learned from you whenever I read your useful comments, Thank you again

@EMett In terms of your original binding issue, ensure that your dynamic properties all raise INotifyPropertyChanged. You may be missing that. "The Async method works well elsewhere, it is just the dropdown part of the combobox which seems to have a problem with being notified of refreshed data" - Please post a minimal  example that shows how you configure and use the ComboBox and how you update the data items and the data item itself. Post all code that you need help with, please.

@MustafaMutasim Thanks for your appreciation. You seem to be a very kind person. Thank you.


MyViewModel.cs
public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public partial class ModelComboBox : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        int _ID = 0;
        [ObservableProperty]
        string _DateInfo = string.Empty;
        [ObservableProperty]
        string _CityInfo = string.Empty;
        [ObservableProperty]
        int _Value_1 = 0;
        [ObservableProperty]
        int _Value_2 = 0;
        [ObservableProperty]
        int _Value_3 = 0;
        [ObservableProperty]
        int _Value_4  = 0;
        [ObservableProperty]
        Visibility _ProgressBarVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    public ObservableCollection<ModelComboBox> OB_TEST { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ModelComboBox>();
   
    List<Task> List_Task_FillValues = new List<Task>();

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task RefreshDataAsync()
    {
        OB_TEST.Clear();
        List_Task_FillValues.Clear();
        //------------------------------
        OB_TEST.Add(new ModelComboBox() { ID = 1, DateInfo = "Tuesday 16/01/2024", CityInfo = "Birmingham" });
        OB_TEST.Add(new ModelComboBox() { ID = 2, DateInfo = "Wednesday 10/01/2024", CityInfo = "London" });
        OB_TEST.Add(new ModelComboBox() { ID = 3, DateInfo = "Tuesday 23/01/2024", CityInfo = "Germany" });

        foreach (var item in OB_TEST)
        {
            List_Task_FillValues.Add(LoadFromFakeDB(item));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(List_Task_FillValues);
    }

    private  async Task LoadFromFakeDB(ModelComboBox item)
    {
        item.ProgressBarVisibility = Visibility.Visible;

        //to simulate a delay
        await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(2000, 6000));
        //-----------------------------------
        item.Value_1 = new Random().Next(0, 200);
        item.Value_2 = new Random().Next(0, 200);
        item.Value_3 = new Random().Next(0, 200);
        item.Value_4 = new Random().Next(0, 200);

        item.ProgressBarVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}

MainWindow markup
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Refresh Data" Command="{Binding RefreshDataCommand}"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding OB_TEST}" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Right" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateInfo,IsAsync=true}" Width="200"/>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,3"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
                                    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                                </Style>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value_1}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value_2}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value_3}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value_4}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <ProgressBar Margin="5" Visibility="{Binding ProgressBarVisibility}" IsIndeterminate="True" Opacity="0.9"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>

                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>


You really should grey out incomplete data items. The user does not know that data is missing. It's really confusing when items suddenly change their content after it was made available. The user will always think that what he sees is what he gets. You would never expect that a data row in a static list will suddenly change its content after a random time.

You didn't even show a busy indicator to at least hint that the view is incomplete (the user would still not know what he's waiting for as all data appear to be ready). Additionally, your MVVM example implies that it is ok to access the database from the view instead of the model which makes it an unrealistic MVVM example. The data is always provided by the view model.

You can't avoid to incrementally update the properties of the data items, which will result in multiple iterations over the complete list (one iteration for each arriving data attribute) which I would expect to rather degrade the performance instead of improving it. The solution is to only add complete data items to the source collection. If you want to show something to the user, then show a busy indicator and placeholders.

That's a totally wrong design thats why I created as wiki, you've explained all its defects, _You didn't even show a busy indicator _ I will add it but will not make it even better

I see. Sorry. This post comes over like a suggested solution. If you would move the data update logic to the view model class (or the data source), then this could be a useful example to show how to dynamically update data in the UI. Then you can remove the dynamic data simulation from the controls. It may (because he's not shown any implementation details) help the OP to fix his binding issues.

Just as an annotation to this example: the UC_ComboBox_Column2 is not a requirement. The main point is to have a data source that implements a property changed notification (e.g. by implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface or dependency properties). This way property changes are propagated by the binding engine, whther the binding itself is async or not.

@BionicCode, This post comes over like a suggested solution yes, UC_ComboBox_Column2 is not a requirement yes I can remove it, I'm going to update it

@BionicCode, Updated
